# How to combine two lists with same order

Tags: python, list

I am trying to learn Python for only few days, very newbie.

Here is the code:

```
Tc = [ (5/9*(i-32)) for i in range(20,81,5) ]

Tc=[round(v,2) for v in Tc]
Tc = [str(Tc)+" Celsius" for Tc in Tc]
#print (Tc)
print(*[item +'\n' for item in Tc])
Tf=[Tf+5 for Tf in range(15,81,5)]
Tf= [str("{:.2f}".format(Tf) )+" Farenheit" for Tf in Tf]
#print(Tf)
print(*[item +'\n' for item in Tf])
```

I want to make it:

```
-6.67 Celsius or 20.00 Fahrenheit
 -3.89 Celsius or 25.00 Fahrenheit
**(and others the same)**
```

Please help

I tried to google it for few hours and tried different codes, but this is the furthest I could. I would be pleased if someone could help

Comment: try something like `for i in range(len(Tc)): do_something(Tc[i],Tf[i])`

Answer (score 1):

Don't print them separately. Print them together, using a simple for loop.

```
Tc = [ (5/9*(i-32)) for i in range(20,81,5) ]
Tc = [round(v,2) for v in Tc]
Tc = [str(Tc)+" Celsius" for Tc in Tc]

Tf = [Tf+5 for Tf in range(15,81,5)]
Tf = [str("{:.2f}".format(Tf) )+" Farenheit" for Tf in Tf]

for i in range(len(Tc)):
    print(Tc[i],"or",Tf[i])
```

Comment: thnak you for help! I was very close to ths solution, but made mistake in last print, instead of comma I used "+"

Answer (score 0):

You can print them as tuples, using built-in [zip](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) function:

```py
print(list(zip(Tc, Tf)))

>>> [('-6.67 Celsius', '20.00 Farenheit'), ('-3.89 Celsius', '25.00 Farenheit'), ...]

# or iterating:

for tc, tf in zip(Tc, Tf):
    print(f"{tc} or {tf}")

>>> 
-6.67 Celsius or 20.00 Farenheit
-3.89 Celsius or 25.00 Farenheit
```

Comment: Thanks. I am still learning and apreciate your help. Honestly, the book asks a little easier question than I am asking here (Create a list comprehension to find Celsius temperatures for Fahrenheit temperatures between 20F and 80F at 5 F increments. The Fahrenheit-Celsius conversion formula is: ...) And the given answer is also simplified: temp_C = [ 5./9.*(i-32) for i in range(20, 81, 5)]  print(temp_C)

Answer (score 0):

```
    Tc = [(5/9 * (i - 32)) for i in range(20, 81, 5)]
     #(Tc)  calculate  Celsius  values in separate lists

     Tf = [(i * 9/5 + 32) for i in range(20, 81, 5)] 
     #(Tf)Fahrenheit values in separate lists.

     for c, f in zip(Tc, Tf):
        print("{:.2f} Celsius or {:.2f} Fahrenheit".format(c, f))
```

loop to iterate through each temperature and print them in the desired format using string formatting ({:.2f} ensures two decimal places**

Comment: thanks for help (I am learning python for few days didn't know about "zip"). Honestly, the book asks a little easier question than I am asking here (Create a list comprehension to find Celsius temperatures for Fahrenheit temperatures between 20F and 80F at 5 F increments. The Fahrenheit-Celsius conversion formula is: ...)
And the given answer is also simplified:
`temp_C = [ 5./9.*(i-32) for i in range(20, 81, 5)]

print(temp_C)`